# 'throw' from within bsync.compare crashes node?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, concurrency, promise, bcrypt

I'm sure this is a novice question, but I've only been having a go at learning express/node/react for a month or so now.

I'm just trying to make a simple node signin REST API call. Here's a snippet of code, with some 'pseudo-izing' of the unimportant parts for brevity:

```js
server.post('/signin', (request, response) => {
    const {user_email, password} = request.body

    // query db for user validation
    db('user_login')
    /* knex query building, blah blah blah */
    .then(res => {
        if (res.length == 0) {
            // if res.length == 0, user not found
            throw new Error("bad credentials")
        } else if (res.length > 1) {
            // if res.length > 1, duplicate user found - shouldn't ever happen
            throw new Error("CRITICAL: database error")
        } else {
            // everything should be ok - pass res on to bcrypt
            return res
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        // bcrypt.compare doesn't return a promise because it is being given a cb
        bcrypt.compare(password, res[0].pw_hash, (err, match) => {
            if (match) {
                // delete pw_hash from any possible response(),
                // don't give client more info than it needs
                delete res[0].pw_hash

                // we have a match! inform the client
                response.json(res[0])
            } else {
                // we don't have a match
                throw new Error("bad credentials")  // WHY DOES THIS THROW CRASH!??!?!!?!?
            }
        })
    })
    // WHY ISNT THIS REACHED WHEN THERE'S A PASSWORD MISMATCH?
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('signin error: ', err)
        response.status(403).json({
            name: err.message,
            severity: 'auth error',
            code: 403
        })
    })
})
```

Ok so:
 - When a correct username and correct password is supplied, it functions as expected.
 - When an incorrect username is supplied, the .catch is reached (ie. functions as expected).
 - BUT: when a correct username and an **incorrect** password is supplied, the throw statement (with the comment // WHY DOES THIS THROW CRASH?)... crashes node.

Here's the call stack:

```
C:\.............\server.js:83
                throw new Error("bad credentials")      // WHY DOES THIS THROW CRASH!??!?!!?!?
                ^

Error: bad credentials
    at C:\.............\server.js:83:23
    at C:\.............\node_modules\bcrypt-nodejs\bCrypt.js:689:3
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I could "cheat" and just do a response.status(403).... instead of that throw. But in my mind, throwing that error ought to jump to the .catch, and handle any auth failure there.

Can anyone help me w/ what's going on here? It's very frustrating.

PS. This crash only seems to be happening when the throw is *within* the bcrypt.compare callback. I figure that has something to do with it. I've googled.. I've looked around on here.. I've wrapped things in try/catch blocks. I'm just beating my head against it at this point.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Ok, after looking into the code for bcrypt.compare, I can only assume that this is happening because bcrypt.compare calls compareSync through process.nextTick. so the throw isn't on the same "chain" as all the rest of the promises. I'm still tinkering trying to find a way around it

Answer (score 0):

Do not `throw` an error from Node like this. You notice that the bcrypt callback has an `err` parameter. Send that back and handle it how you want to in the back or front.